# Can a XAMARIN.IOS app project use CoreBluetooth? I cannot find example/tutorial/guide

Tags: ios, xamarin.ios, bluetooth-lowenergy, core-bluetooth

I need my Xamarin.IOS app to communicate with our embedded BLE device.

Cannot find example or guide for Xamarin.IOS using CoreBluetooth.

Tried BLE plugins but all have build or run errors.  (WOJ, ARITCHIE, XABRE)

Can my Xamarin.IOS app truly use CoreBluetooth, or should I use plugin BLE?

Comment: I think you can use Core Bluetooth in Xamarin.iOS, it's just like the same usage of native iOS.

Comment: I think you're right.  I'm now exploring: https://wojciechkulik.pl/xamarin-ios/how-to-communicate-with-bluetooth-low-energy-devices-on-ios